# Bound on the derivative of a bounded polynomial with bounded degree (over an interval)

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Assume $p(x)\in \mathbb R [x]$ is a polynomial of degree no more than $n$, such that on the interval $I=[a,b],a<b$ we have $|p(x)|<c$ for some constant $c$. I wonder if there exists a bound
$M=M(I,n,c)$ such that the derivative $p'(x)$ is bounded by $M$ on $I$.

This question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3662705/bounds-for-the-coefficients-for-a-family-of-polynomials) I asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p(x) = \sum_k a_k x^k$ where $a = (a_0,a_1,...,a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, define the norm $\|p\| = \max_{t \in [0,1]} |p(t)|$ and note that this is equivalent to any norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Note that the derivative $Dp = p'$ can be identified with $(a_1, 2a_2,..., n a_n, 0)$ and hence the map is linear and hence continuous and bounded (as a linear operator).

Hence if $\|p\| < c$ then $\|p'\| \le \|D\| \|p\| \le \|D\| c$.

Comment: It seems to me that  you treat a polynomial both as a vector in R^n+1 and as a smooth function. Why is the max norm of a smooth function equivalent to the vector norm of coefficients? I think the equivalence is very nontrivial. It's not the equivalence between different norms on finite dim vector spaces.

Comment: The space of polynomials of degree at most $n$ is a finite dimensional space spanned by the basis $x\mapsto x^k$ for $k=0,...,n$. All norms on this space are equivalent. One norm is, say, the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ another is $\max_{t \in [0,1]} |\sum_k a_k t^k|$.